# OSB Proxy rejects as 400 bad data from upstream system but still works from SOAP UI or postman

Tags: http-post, osb

We have a HTTP transport proxy service and it works as expected when we post using post man or SOAP UI with all the URL params as we receive from upstream application but when we do intergtration testing, it is not hitting the service and responds 400 Bad data request to the upstream application.

Flow is like HTTP post from upstream application --> VIP server --> OSB Server. 
We installed snoop on OSB server and it captured the request from upstream and also i could see below entry in access log of that particular domain.

10.128.30.140 - - [08/Jan/2018:11:02:29 +0000] "" 400 0

But if do POST using SOAP UI, it is like

10.204.7.14 - - [08/Jan/2018:10:41:23 +0000] "POST /URLProxy HTTP/1.0" 200 1

Not getting much clue on why it is considered as bad data request and couldn't find much info in server logs. 
It was Java application that was migrated to OSB and upstream system didnt change any except the HTTP post URL. It still works well with legacy Java application.

Update - Could find below error in domain log of admin server. Planning to enable HTTP debug logs and see if it can throw some light.

MWOSBDomain.log00128:####      <> <>  <1515151593009>

Comment: What weblogic/osb version are you using? We had an issue in 11.1.1.4 were we received HTTP 400 bad request. We tried to find the issue with Oracle support but couldn't find it. We upgraded to 11.1.1.7 and the issue was fixed.

Comment: We are using 11.1.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle DOC ID 1608951 has steps to enable the HTTP logs and it gives more light on the exact issue. In our case, it was due to no carriage return after HTTP/1.0 and upstream system sends with additional space. We changed it using available content switch with the help of networks team. Just leaving it here as it could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it seems the caller is not using a proper **HTTP method** *(notice how the SOAPui call is calling an http **POST** method on context /URLProxy)* or your VIP is not routing it properly.

Comment: We enabled HTTP logs and could see below error which related to your answer. "Protocol was not set"